# how do i echo value onto log using selenium ide 2.4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I tried 
 `echo value is ${v1}`

but then the value does not appear instead

`echo value is`

is render

can someone tell how can i achieve so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code should work for you. Suppose you have stored amount 15 to variable X, then echo will return echo: 15

```
store | 15 | X
echo  | ${X} |
```